# Delphi {Form1} fails if WriteLN is present

Tags: delphi

I have a Delphi code where the program has a unit with `{Form1}` next to it. That unit uses another unit where I have try/except procedure and write a message to the screen. Below are the code snippets for detailed explanation.

Important Note1 : **I tried to elaborate my question and re-posted it. I hope this is clear.**

Important Note2 : **If I remove the WriteLn inside the  exception (third code snippet below) the code  works even if it is called from GUI**

Main Program

```
program PROGNAME;

uses
  Forms,
  View in 'FView.pas' {Form1},
  SubUnit in 'FSubUnit.pas';
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Form1.Left := Screen.WorkAreaLeft;
  Form1.Top := Screen.WorkAreaTop;
  Application.Run;
end
```

In Fview.pas I have

```
procedure TForm1.FileListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
ReadData(filename);
end
```

In SUBUNIT which reads data I HAVE

```
try
    Read(F, result);
  except  // IO error
    on E: EInOutError do
    begin
      writeln('No info is given default taken')
    end;
  end;
```

Normally my code works and skips if there is an IO error with the above warning. If I do the same and call from the GUI I get a screen message IOError and it does not move on the

Is this a common issue? Do I need to suppress that part of the code?

Comment: This is the same question as the closed one you deleted just now, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62659565/576719. This is not a valid behaviour according to SO guidelines.

Comment: yes I elaborated and added the extra code snippets

Comment: Then put that into the closed one. If enough effort was made to make the question clear it will be reopened.

Comment: We can close this one too, since it lacks a [mcve]

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Pretty sure the OP is trying to do output to the console in a GUI app that has no console.

Comment: I deleted that question as this was the first time ever my question was closed so i was not aware that it would be reopened. I will delete both and probably will try to minimize my delphi related questions. I have used stackoverflow for many other languages in years and it seems that any delphi question is dominated by the few people who have constant harsh comments. (which I also hope that "is not a valid behaviour according to SO guidelines")

Comment: @user2375049: You may want to read my answer before you delete the Q! :)

Comment: Even though i read the answer i wanted to express myself with that comment. I will have a try with your answer.

Comment: Whyy do you keep puttiing `{Form1}` in your qs?  Have you not noticed that no-one else does it, and it certainly doesn't clarify anything?

Comment: Can I please urge you, again, to include the full text of the error message, and the line on which it is raised. This really does matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is exepcted.

`Writeln` writes output to the console. A GUI application (by default) has no console.

Hence, if you do `Writeln('No info...')` in a typical GUI app, you tell the system to write `'No info...'` to the console, but there is no console! Hence the I/O error (105, I assume).

Either add a console manually to your GUI app (`AllocConsole`), or -- probably much better -- use a GUI error message instead: `ShowMessage('No info...')` or `MessageBox(Handle, 'No info...', 'My App', MB_ICONERROR)`.

Comment: is there a way completely suppress this message if it is called from Form1 like unit.

Comment: I think you can do `if IsConsole then
      Writeln('Error')
    else
      ShowMessage('Error');` This will output to the console in a console app, and display a message box in a GUI app. (I don't remember if the test is the optimal one, though.)

Comment: ShowMessage. works and the user has to click OK button. But the if IsConsole is always false somehow.

Comment: @user2375049: Even in a console application?

Comment: Remove the try/except and let the top level exception handler handle it. Classic novice mistake is to try to handle exceptions. Just ignore them and let the VCL deal with them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That of course depends on the context. But very likely your suggestion is a good one in this case. And of course the OP should also consider to abandon old-school Pascal I/O.

Comment: what is the new I/O method of Pascal

Comment: @user2375049: There are actually several ways, but they are all based on ordinary classes or records. For text files, there is the old `TStringList` and `TFile.ReadAllText`/`ReadAllLines` (in `IOUtils.pas` since D2010) as well as streams. For binary data, there is `TFile.ReadAllBytes` and streams.